# Page up/down without moving cursor (looking for opposite of ^e)

Tags: vim

Randomly while working I found the command `^e` which allowed me to page down without the cursor moving off its current line. I'm wondering what the opposite is for paging up.

Its really helpful when trying to see a few more lines down the screen without having to move the cursor from its current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `scroll.txt`:

```
CTRL-Y                  Scroll window [count] lines upwards in the buffer.
```

Comment: [Vim scroll documentation on Sourceforge](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html)

Comment: Or start with `:h Ctrl-E`.